# how to give the hyperlink in <td> tag for flask deletion method

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

how to give the hyper link for flask deletion method. Here it is the code HTML code. I have written in HTML   for hyperlink. So, how to give pass the url in flask route.
I'm working with a Flask framework, and I am trying to delete an entry from the database. The code below gives this error: "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
{{super()}}
{% endblock %}
{% block navbar %}
{{super()}}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="#">
<em class="fa fa-home"></em> </a></li>
<li class="active">Users>View/Edit</li>
</ol>
</div><!--/.row-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">

<thead>
<tr>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>
       Email
   </th>
   <th>
       Address
   </th>
   <th>
       Aadharimage
   </th>

   <th>
       Password
   </th>
   <th>
      Locations
   </th>
   <th>
      Dateofsub
   </th>
   <th>
     Lastlogin
   </th>
   <th>
     Control
</th>
<th>
Delete
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
{% for values in endusers   %}
<tr>
<td>{{values.name}}</td>
<td>{{values.email}}</td>
<td>{{values.address}}</td>
<td> <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='assets/images     /{{values.aadharimage}}')}}"  width="24" height="24">{{values.aadharimage}}</td>`   
<!-- <td><img src=" {{url_for('static', filename=' /assets/images/tms.png')}}" width="25" height="50"/></td>-->
<td>********</td>
<td>{{values.locations}}</td> 
<td>{{values.dateofsub}}</td>
<td>{{values.lastlogin}}</td>
<td><a href="/Control/resetuserpass/{{values.id}}" class="btn btninfo">Reset Password</a></td>
<td><a href="{{ url_for('delete_user', postID=values.id) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
<a href = "/page/new user"> <em class="fa fa-xl fa-plus-circle color-blue"></em> </a>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}


Here is the flask code this is correct ? I am trying for 2 days please solve  this problem. While running thus code it showing 404 and 405 method.




@app.route('/delete/<int:postID>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_user(postID):
if not session.get('logged_in'):
     abort(401)
sqlsession.execute('delete from values WHERE id = ?', [postID])
flash('Entry was deleted')
return redirect(url_for('pageedituser'))
```

Comment: Browsers will never send a DELETE method. But in any case a link will only ever be a GET, and you **must not** do destructive operations on a GET. You should use a form with a button.

Comment: could you give brief detail    @daniel.

Answer (score 5):

In your HTML you've constructed a GET method. Change your methods to GET will solve this problem but that's not the correct answer. The answer is to use HTML form to make the POST request to your flask server.

*html*

```
<form action="{{ url_for('delete_user', postID=values.id) }}" method="POST">
</form>
```

*view*

```
@app.route('/delete/<int:post_id>', methods=['POST'])
```

**Improved answer**

If you want DELETE request to flask use Javascript, I suggest to use `fetch`

> The HTML form element cannot be used for anything other than POST or GET directly, so any support for other methods should be done via XMLHttpRequest in javascript.

i.e)

*html*

```
<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deletePost(23);">Delete</a></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function deletePost(postId) {
      return fetch('http://localhost:5000/delete' + '/' + postId, {
        method: 'delete'
      }).then(response =>
        console.log(response)
      );
    }
</script>
```